# reading multiple labels as a list or tuples in a dict with id as the key i.e {id:(cat1,cat2,.....)}

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, machine-learning, text-analysis, multilabel-classification

I am modelling a multilabel text classifcation algorithm. Below is a snipet of my labels.txt file I want to convert these records into a dictionary consisting of the id with corresponding categories in a tuple or a list i.e {id:(cat1,cat2)}. The records are not new line seperated. I am stuck on how to convert this kind of data into dictionary.

```
B0027DQHA0
  Movies & TV, TV
  Music, Classical
0756400120
  Books, Literature & Fiction, Anthologies & Literary Collections, General
  Books, Literature & Fiction, United States
  Books, Science Fiction & Fantasy, Science Fiction, Anthologies
  Books, Science Fiction & Fantasy, Science Fiction, Short Stories
B0000012D5
  Music, Blues
  Music, Pop
  Music, R&B
```

Comment: Heh "SOlution". Very nice :)

Comment: That being said, select the answer instead of copying it into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If category names are always indented with spaces and IDs are not, you can use this to distinguish them and append category names to lists in a dict indexed by IDs in a loop:

```
r = '''B0027DQHA0
  Movies & TV, TV
  Music, Classical
0756400120
  Books, Literature & Fiction, Anthologies & Literary Collections, General
  Books, Literature & Fiction, United States
  Books, Science Fiction & Fantasy, Science Fiction, Anthologies
  Books, Science Fiction & Fantasy, Science Fiction, Short Stories
B0000012D5
  Music, Blues
  Music, Pop
  Music, R&B'''
d = {}
for l in r.splitlines():
    if l.startswith(' '):
        d.setdefault(i, []).append(l.lstrip())
    else:
        i = l
print(d)
```

This outputs:

```
{'B0027DQHA0': ['Movies & TV, TV', 'Music, Classical'], '0756400120': ['Books, Literature & Fiction, Anthologies & Literary Collections, General', 'Books, Literature & Fiction, United States', 'Books, Science Fiction & Fantasy, Science Fiction, Anthologies', 'Books, Science Fiction & Fantasy, Science Fiction, Short Stories'], 'B0000012D5': ['Music, Blues', 'Music, Pop', 'Music, R&B']}
```

Comment: Its giving me an error. Please see the Updated original question!

Comment: In my example above `r` is a string, so I used `r.splitlines()` to get a list of lines, but if your `r` is a file object you can just iterate over it with `for l in r:`.

Comment: Yeah i did vote but it wont be visible publicly as my reputation is below 15

Comment: Voting and accepting an answer are different. You can accept an answer by clicking on the grey check mark next to an answer. A reputation of 1 can do it too. :-)

Comment: ohh okayy Done!! (Y)